# Store number from in datatable but Culture specific

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, multilingual, cultureinfo

I have spent so much time trying to figure out how numbers work in different cultures in C#. I have sorted all the scenarios except when adding a number to datatable. In db I have number in US format (e.g. 1.32), in frontend if the culture is german then it show 1,32 in grid.

I can convert 1.32 to 1,32 using

```
Convert.ToDouble("1.32").ToString(Culture.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

but when I add this into a data table in a column of type double it becomes 132.0.

the number in db is of type double. This is how I try to convert it into proper culture format:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5]).ToString(culture.NumberFormat) })
```

One way would be to format the number in rowdatabound event of grid but is this a proper solution? There should be a way to store culture specific number in datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the value to the database/datatable it should be of type double not string. A double value does not care about formatting, only when it is converted (and displayed) as a string.

As for formatting goes, the GridView uses the culture specified in [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (can be changed from code). But you can also set you specific formatting on BoundField using property [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Comment: thanks for quick response. the number in db is of type double.

Comment: Yeh, but how do you save the value from your application to the DB?

Comment: Double.Parse(txtPrice.Text.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: I would recommend changing the global culture using  `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` instead of formatting individual values to different cultures using `ToString(SomeCulture)`.

Comment: The current culture is german. Everywhere people say that things are done according to the culture but in my case the culture is german but everything is happening in english culture.

Comment: if you add the following code to your page: `double d = 1.25; Response.Write(d.ToString());` what would the result be?

Comment: your point about bound field gave me an idea that I can set format of the column like this: gridView1.Columns[5].DisplayFormat.Format = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat; and it worked. thanks man!!

Comment: Good! Note that `CurrentUICulture` and `CurrentCulture` is not the same thing, one is for language and the other for numbers and dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to add a string to a DataTable field of type double, it will be parsed using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` - which presumably has period as a decimal separator in your case.

You should add the double directly to the DataTable, rather than formatting it as a string in a different culture (de-DE):

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(..., Convert.ToDouble("1.32"), ...);
```

rather than:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(..., Convert.ToDouble("1.32").ToString(anotherCulture), ...);
```

Subsequently you can change the culture used to display the value from the DataTable - how you do this depends on how you are displaying it, but one way is:

```
((double) dataRow["MyDoubleColumn"]).ToString(anotherCulture);
```

Comment: current culture is German. When adding number to datatable if I dont do any formatting then the it is shown in grid as it is stored in db i.e. 1.32. 

I am binding data table to a grid so according to your suggestion I will do the formatting in row bound event?

Comment: If CurrentCulture is set to german and you a displaying the value in a BoundField it should format correctly, are you sure your not converting it to a string in the DB before returning it?

Comment: I was not converting the value in db. I set the column format and it worked perfectly. thanks!